# What is the meaning of the following expressions?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_n,\ldots$ be a sequence of events. What is the meaning of these events:
$$A^*=\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{n=k}^{\infty}A_n$$
$$A_*=\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{n=k}^{\infty}A_n$$
My attempt: I think $A^*$ means that $$\forall N\in \mathbb{N}: \exists n > N: A_n=1$$ and $A_*$ means that $$\exists N\in\mathbb{N}: \forall n>N: A_n=1$$
Am I right? Maybe there are some logical explanation of these expressons beside that only mathematical formula meaning

Comment: What do you mean by $A_n=1$?

Comment: I mean that $A_n$ has happened

Comment: What you've written is confusing, since if I read your intent correctly, in one formula you write events as sets of outcomes, and another formula express an event as a random proposition, and within that formula you use an event in the form of a random integer-encoded truth value. I think your writing would be less confusing if you picked *one* of these methods and stuck with it. Or, at the very least, actually explain you're doing so.

Comment: Happened with probability 1, or happened, period? Anyway, I think you may want to clarify in standard language what it is that you mean.

Comment: I wanted to describe the fact that $A_*$ and $A^*$ happened, just happened. So in first expression, as I think, it means that there is at least one 1 in every () and in the second expression it means, that there is a moment that after some N there are all 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you mean something like:
$$
A^* = \{x \mid (\forall N\in\mathbb{N})(\exists n\ge N)\,x\in A_n\}
$$
and
$$
A_* = \{x \mid (\exists N\in\mathbb{N})(\forall n\ge N)\,x\in A_n\}.
$$

These sets are commonly called $\limsup_n A_n$ and $\liminf_n A_n$, respectively. It can be useful to describe these sets in words:

$\limsup_n A_n$ (which is $A^*$) is the set of all points that are in $A_n$ for infinitely many $n$

and

$\liminf_n A_n$ (which is $A_*$) is the set of all points that are in $A_n$ for all but finitely many $n$.

There are many analogues to the limit superior and inferior of sequences of real numbers that justify this notation. Scroll down on [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior) see more about them.

Comment: I had to up-vote this myself!

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
A^* &= \bigcap_{k=1}^\infty \left( A_k \cup A_{k+1} \cup \cdots \right) \\
&=  \left( A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \cdots \right) \cap  \left( A_2 \cup A_3 \cup \cdots \right) \cap \cdots
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}
A_* &= \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty \left( A_k \cap A_{k+1} \cap \cdots \right) \\
&=  \left( A_1 \cap A_2 \cap \cdots \right) \cup  \left( A_2 \cap A_3 \cap \cdots \right) \cup \cdots \\
\end{align}$$

I’m not sure if there’s much more we can know about $A^*$ and $A_*$ without having a general formula for $A_i$. I’ll update this if I think of anything.

Comment: We don't have any formula on $A_i$. I wrote all the text that I had on this problem. Its goal is to interpret this expressions in some way

Comment: @ioleg19029700 Better stick with John Griffin’s answer then